# Bulk collect skips Insert on large tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulkinsert

I have a procedure from which I insert into 6 tables, using BULK COLLECT. It works based on date interval. Procedure inserts in 3 tables, but skips insert on 3 larger tables. My procedure is like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MULTI_INSERT 
IS

--Variable for rowtype (I assigned only one for all tables, because they have same construction - size and columns - just different names)
TYPE aa IS TABLE OF Table1%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
my_insert aa;

--Dates
first_day DATE;
this_day DATE := SYSDATE;

--Variable for deleting tables & checking if table has rows
No_of_records NUMBER; 
Delete_tables VARCHAR(5):=  to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd.mm');

BEGIN

--Delete tables in January
IF Delete_tables = '10.01' THEN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE Table1';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE Table2';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE Table3';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE Table4';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE Table5';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE Table6';

END IF;

BEGIN --Insert of 1st table

--check number of records - function
 No_of_records :=empty_table('Table1');

  IF No_of_records = 1 then

      SELECT MAX(DATUM) +1 into first_day FROM Table1;
  ELSIF No_of_records = 0 then

     SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR') "First Day" INTO first_day FROM Dual ;
  END IF;

SELECT... --queries are different in each BEGIN END block !

FORALL i IN 1..my_insert.LAST
INSERT INTO Table1  (Name,Surname,Address,Join_Year,Start_Date)
VALUES(my_insert(i).Name,my_insert(i).Surname,my_insert(i).Address,my_insert(i).join_Year,my_insert(i).Start_Date);

COMMIT;
END;

BEGIN

--...And so on...Same code, just different queries for inserts into different tables...

COMMIT;
END;

END MULTI_INSERT;
/
```

What could be the cause of skipping inserts ? ... As you probably noticed I don't assign **null** to **my_insert** after every Insert, but I've read that BULK COLLECT does that automatically before fetching data. And I also wrote **BEGIN END** block for each Insert, with wish to not stop other Inserts If one of them fails ( but I'm not quite sure If that's the way to go).

Comment: The inserts are driven by the selects. Presumably these are selecting into PL/SQL collections. There is something different about either what you have coded for handling the larger tables or something the same which should be different. We can't help you without seeing the actual code which isn't working. You don't have to post the whole procedure but we need to see an example of the code for a table which works and for one which doesn't work.

Comment: @APC, thanks for response. About a procedure - there aren't any differences in any of the Inserts, except queries - meaning different Joins and conditions in Where clause. Everything else is exactly same. To explain further - If I comment out other Inserts and execute procedure with only 1 insert, then all Inserts are done correctly. But I don't wish to have 6 procedures for that.

Comment: Okay, this is one of those weird seeming things which will have a perfectly obvious explanation. But alas, unless you post **a reproducible test case** there's more much we can do expect commiserate with your troubles and wish you good luck in solving this.

Comment: @APC, I believe I couldn't post **a reproducible test case** while I have some Inserts with over 50 millions of rows, my title says about skipping LARGE tables, not all of them. Beside that, I tried to reset record variable with **my_insert.delete;** and so far It looks like that was an issue. Though I'll need a few hours to confirm It.

Comment: It seems more likely that the issue is with the code, and not in the PL/SQL bulk collect mechanism randomly skipping inserts on large tables. I’m pretty sure it doesn’t do that.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, I haven't think of anything like that. I was suspecting that something is wrong with **"my_insert"** variable, because I use It for inserts into all tables. And so far **my_insert.delete;"** seems to solve my problems, but I'm not sure If I should leave It like that, although all tables are same (same columns, and sizes). Though testing is still fine, almost 50% of test allready done.